# Inductive Proof that $\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt k \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

Help me understand this :

$$\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}$$

Comment: Must you use induction? It can be shown directly. If not, can you share the induction proof and what you don't understand about it?

Comment: Are you  kidding? It is obvious, since $\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt k=\dfrac 1{\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt k}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $K\geq 0$ we have
$K^2\leq K^2+K=K(K+1)$ and so
$K\leq \sqrt{K(K+1)}$ which further implies
$K+1\leq \sqrt{K(K+1)}+1,$
Thus we have
$K+1-\sqrt{K(K+1)}\leq 1,$ or
$\sqrt{K+1}\left(  \sqrt{K+1} -\sqrt{K}\right)\leq 1,$ which is the required inequality.